# Access variable from error_handler

Tags: php, ajax, json, scope, custom-error-handling

I have a php file that is only accessed through ajax. The ajax call expects only data formatted as a `json_encode`d output. I am trying to make a custom error handler function that catches php errors, and rather than outputting them directly, instead passes them to the array they is encoded for the json parser.

So far I have

```
// error handler function
function handleErrors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    $response['php_error'][] = "Error [$errno] - $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile";

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

set_error_handler("handleErrors");

//do other stuff that might trigger php errors

if ($result===true){
    $response['success'] = true;
}else{
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['error'] = $result;
    $response['request'] = json_encode($_REQUEST);
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

My issue is that the `$response` array is out of scope for the rest of the document to access so that it will be output in the json object. Is there some way of passing a variable by reference into the custom function or another way I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a OOP context you can define `$response` as a property.

```
class myclass {

    var $response;

    function __construct()
    {
        set_error_handler(array($this, 'handleErrors'));
    }

    function handleErrors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        if ( ! (error_reporting() & $errno))
        {
            // This error code is not included in error_reporting
            return;
        }

        $this->response['php_error'][] = "Error [$errno] - $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile";

        /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
        return true;
    }

    function outputAjax()
    {
        // my code

        if ($result === true)
        {
            $this->response['success'] = true;
        } else
        {
            $this->response['success'] = false;
            $this->response['error'] = $result;
            $this->response['request'] = json_encode($_REQUEST);
        }

        echo json_encode($this->response);
    }

}
```

Comment: So to 'run' this function I would just do `$foo = new myClass(); $foo->outputAjax();` ? I'm pretty new when it comes to classes in PHP.

Comment: You got it... (and remember $globals are evil)

Answer (score 2):

Define $response as global in you function

```
function handleErrors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    global $response;
    //further code..
}
```

OR use $GLOBALS

```
$GLOBALS['response']['php_error'][] = "Error [$errno] - $errstr on line $errline in file $errfile";
```

Comment: Ah of course. I have had the "don't use globals" mantra drummed in to me so hard I forgot there is a time and a place for them.

Comment: Please don't use globals. They're not really the answer to anything. At the very least, use a public static property of a class, or even an instantiated object, but not a global. Something like `Blah::$php_errors[] = ...` would be cleaner.